# Iterating through a vector cause error but standard for-loop does not

Tags: c++, loops, stl, vector, iterator

I have a `vector` that holds pointers to abstract type `Rock`:

```
vector<Rock*> rocks;
```

If I loop through the vector with an iterator and then try to access the object (a non-abstract class that extends `Rock`) via the iterator, I get an 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' error in XCode 4:

```
vector<Rock*>::iterator rockIter;
for (rockIter = rocks.begin(); rockIter != rocks.end(); ++rockIter)
{
  bullet.hit(*(*rockIter));
}
```

But looping through it normally like is no problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rocks.size(); i++)
{
  bullet.hit(*rocks[i]);
}
```

The function `hit()` looks like:

```
bool Bullet::hit(Rock & rock)
```

I thought that `*(*rockIter)` and `*rock[i]` would do the same thing but clearly they dont.  What is different, and how can I pass a reference of an object in the vector via an iterator like I do with `*rock[i]`?

Comment: It's worth mentioning you'll want to use a vector of smart pointers instead of raw pointers. They make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing more code I'm not sure if this is the problem, but is the code in `bullet.hit()` changing the vector by adding elements?  If it is and you're iterating over it using an `iterator`, that iterator will get invalidated and any future dereferences on it will result in undefined behavior.  However, using the standard `int`-based for loop will not have this problem, because accesses by index can't be invalidated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah thank you!  This was the issue.  Many layers in from the functions called in `hit()` there was a change in the vector and I completely forgot about it!